# how to delete {} but keep the dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I tried to learn about dictionaries and sets today but I don't know how to use `join` properly.

```
brandin = []
for x in range(int(input("New brand total: "))):
    brand = input("Brand Name: ")
    brandin.append(brand)

brandinset = set(brandin)
print("list: ", ', '.join(brandin))
print("set: ", ', '.join(brandinset))

brandtotal = {}
for brand in brandin:
    if brand in brandtotal:
        brandtotal[brand] += 1
    else:
        brandtotal[brand] = 1

print((brandtotal))
```

and heres the **output:**

```
New brand total: 7
Brand Name: nike
Brand Name: adidas
Brand Name: nike
Brand Name: vans
Brand Name: adidas
Brand Name: nb
Brand Name: puma
list:  nike, adidas, nike, vans, adidas, nb, puma
set:  nike, vans, puma, nb, adidas
{'nike': 2, 'adidas': 2, 'vans': 1, 'nb': 1, 'puma': 1}
```

How do I make `{'nike': 2, 'adidas': 2, 'vans': 1, 'nb': 1, 'puma': 1}`

become like `nike: 2, adidas: 2, vans: 1, nb: 1, puma: 1`

I tried to use `join` but it deleted the **value**.

Comment: One option: `print(','.join(f"{key}: {value}" for key,value in brandtotal.items()))`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thank you!!!! btw what the f does there??

Comment: It's an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). A simpler way to format strings. You could also use `format()` or string concatenation but I prefer f-strings.

Comment: Addendum to @JohnnyMopp's comment (that really seems like it should be an answer): If you're just `print`ing it, and don't need the complete string to exist in memory, you could do: `print(*(f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in brandtotal.items()), sep=', ')` and let `print` handle printing the individual items and inserting the separator on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `join()` :

```
brandtotal = {'nike': 2, 'adidas': 2, 'vans': 1, 'nb': 1, 'puma': 1}
', '.join(k+': '+str(brandtotal[k]) for k in brandtotal.keys())
```

The output is this string:

```
'nike: 2, adidas: 2, vans: 1, nb: 1, puma: 1'
```

Comment: Rather than repeated string concatenation (which is both harder to read and asymptotically slower), I'd suggest using f-strings or `str.format`. I'd also suggest iterating over `.items()` to avoid unnecessary lookups of each key, ending with the faster/simpler: `', '.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in brandtotal.items())`.